# How much vertical space to keep african dwarf frogs from jumping out?

Tags: aquarium, containment, frogs

I have a 20 gallon (76 liters) long tank with a lid to keep my african dwarf frogs in. I'd like to eventually move them to a bigger tank without a lid.

Considering the maximum water height for the frogs are about 12 inches (30 cm), and I'd like 2 - 3 inches (5 - 7.5 cm) of substrate for plants, that would require a minimum of 15 inches (38 cm) of height, plus however high they can jump, plus a few inches for good measure. The problem is I haven't been able to find any data on how high they can jump from the water.

Comment: I had an adf in a 10 gallon tall with a lid and I never saw him try to jump in any way

Comment: You should also keep in mind, that they maybe could climb the sides of the tank...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of anyone keeping them in a tank without a cover before, simply because it's better to be safe than sorry, however on my research journey I did find this interesting tidbit:

> The water level must be dropped 2.5-5.1cm (1-2") from the top for two reasons; one, to allow for proper gas exchange and respiration of the frogs, and two, to prevent escape and therefore death. Otherwise ensure there are no escape holes for the frogs to explore. A DAF can easily jump 7.6-10.2cm (3-4") into the air from a solid base.
>
> ([very interesting source](http://www.theaquariumwiki.com/Hymenochirus_boettgeri))

Comment: This helps a lot. Seems like if I keep about 6 to 8 inches of clearance I should be good.

Comment: Yes I should think so, although I'd keep an eye on them for the first day or so just in case, but I'm over-cautious!

Answer (score 0):

I have two African dwarf frogs in my tank, and I don't really think that you have to keep a lid on. I do have a lid on mine, but I have never seen them try to jump out. Sorry, however I couldn't find the answer to how high they can jump. Overall, I don't think that them jumping out would really be a big problem since they like to hide or just stay at the bottom most of the time. Hope this helps.